# How to compare a date MariaDB

Tags: php, cakephp, mariadb

I have a field called `created_at` where its type is `timestamp` (predefined as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`), when I run the bellow code the query does not works. This code is supposed to bring me all logs within 1 min;

`$sent = $this->Logs->find()->where(['Logs.created_at >=' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 min'))])->where(['Logs.user_id =' => $this->Auth->user('id'), 'Logs.status =' => 1])->all()`;

But if I change the field type to `datetime` it'll work fine. The point is I need the field type be `timestamp`, not datetime.

### SQL debug

```
Cake\ORM\Query Object
(
    [sql] => SELECT Logs.id AS `Logs__id`, Logs.notify_to AS `Logs__notify_to`, Logs.notify_from AS `Logs__notify_from`, Logs.content AS `Logs__content`, Logs.attachment AS `Logs__attachment`, Logs.status AS `Logs__status`, Logs.error AS `Logs__error`, Logs.user_id AS `Logs__user_id`, Logs.typeof AS `Logs__typeof`, Logs.created_at AS `Logs__created_at` FROM logs Logs WHERE (Logs.created_at >= :c0 AND Logs.user_id = :c1 AND Logs.status = :c2)
    [params] => Array
        (
            [:c0] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 2021-05-02 11:26:20
                    [type] => datetime
                    [placeholder] => c0
                )

            [:c1] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 1
                    [type] => integer
                    [placeholder] => c1
                )

            [:c2] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 1
                    [type] => integer
                    [placeholder] => c2
                )

        )
```

### Table records

[image]

### Update

I realized that the record in DB is `2021-05-02 14:58:26` but when I fetch in PHP it shows as `2021-05-02 17:58:26`.

See the image above and the output below

```
object(Cake\ORM\ResultSet)#210 (1) { ["items"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(App\Model\Entity\Log)#203 (19) { ["id"]=> int(4315) ["notify_to"]=> string(12) "558788085188" ["notify_from"]=> string(4) "3513" ["content"]=> string(4) "fdfd" ["attachment"]=> NULL ["status"]=> int(1) ["error"]=> NULL ["user_id"]=> int(1) ["typeof"]=> NULL ["created_at"]=> object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime)#220 (3) { ["time"]=> string(32) "2021-05-02 17:58:26.000000+00:00" ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" ["fixedNowTime"]=> bool(false) } ["[new]"]=> bool(false) ["[accessible]"]=> array(9) { ["notify_to"]=> bool(true) ["notify_from"]=> bool(true) ["content"]=> bool(true) ["attachment"]=> bool(true) ["user_id"]=> bool(true) ["typeof"]=> bool(true) ["created_at"]=> bool(true) ["status"]=> bool(true) ["error"]=> bool(true) } ["[dirty]"]=> array(0) { } ["[original]"]=> array(0) { } ["[virtual]"]=> array(0) { } ["[hasErrors]"]=> bool(false) ["[errors]"]=> array(0) { } ["[invalid]"]=> array(0) { } ["[repository]"]=> string(4) "Logs" } } }
```

### PHP tests

When I call the PHP function `date()` returns the correct time.

Comment: What is the actual SQL query which was generated and executed by this source code?

Comment: Can you add your database screenshot for any record?

Comment: Can you show us an image of your database with record?

Comment: Can you try the sql query directly in ``phpmyadmin``? May be there is an issue in record insertion when field type is set to ``timestamp`` type?

Comment: @RohitMittal I've updated the question with more important explanations.

Answer (score 0):

For who uses CakePHP3.x you need set the `date_default_time_zone()` but weirdly you need also set `timezone` for Database Instance.

**app_local.php**

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'host' => 'localhost',
        /*
         * CakePHP will use the default DB port based on the driver selected
         * MySQL on MAMP uses port 8889, MAMP users will want to uncomment
         * the following line and set the port accordingly
         */
        //'port' => 'non_standard_port_number',
        'username' => 'xxxx',
        'password' => 'xxxxx',
        'database' => 'xxxxx',
        'log' => true,
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
        'timezone' => '-3:00',
    ],
]
```

When CakePHP retrieves records from DB it change according the timezone set on `Datasources`.

Comment: That's exactly how [**the `TIMESTAMP` type**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) is supposed to work, it's not CakePHP doing that. MySQL/MariaDB will convert the value to UTC when saving, and to the current timezone when reading. This is exactly why one would use `TIMESTAMP` over `DATETIME` in the first place. If you don't need that feature, then you don't need the `TIMESTAMP` type.